# Using Autolayout with UIView embedded in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a View embedded inside a Scroll View.  I have written code such that when the cursor is placed in a text field (within the View) that is hidden by the keyboard that the screen will readjust such that the text field is no longer hidden.  I am using autolayout to do this.

My problem is that when I put the View in the View Controller at the position I want it, there is a lot of additional white space above when I run the simulator.  But when the keyboard comes up (and the screen redraws) then I can scroll up and the View Controller no longer has that additional white space.

If I adjust the view so that there isn't any white space (so it appears as on the storyboard) then when the keyboard appears, I cannot scroll to the top of the View.

I assume this has something to do with how the View is centered within the Scroll View but I have tried numerous adjustments on the constraints in the Size Inspector and cannot resolve this.  I would really like to fix this in the storyboard (versus through code) if at all possible...

Here is the code:

```
- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    kbRect = [self.view convertRect:kbRect fromView:nil];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbRect.size.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbRect.size.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void) keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: add the screen shots

Comment: I don't have permission to post a screenshot, but it is View on top of a Scroll View on top of a View Controller.  Here are the constraints in the View:  Height: 358, Trailing Space to: Superview, Leading Space to: Superview, Align Center X to: Superview, Bottom Space to: Superview Equals: 100, Top Space to: Superview Equals 15

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was setting the `EdgeInsets` value too high... when I changed from

`UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbRect.size.height, 0.0);`

to

`UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0, 0.0, kbRect.size.height, 0.0);`

The positioning was improved.